# Can push data to SQL Server database from kaizala data

Tags: kaizala-action

Is it possible to store kaizala data in a SQL Server database and how to integrate kaizala with SQL Server. If any way to do this kindly guide to me.

Answer (score 0):

After raising the case to Microsoft right now no functionality available to access the web service and push data to server.